# How to Take Lowest Quantity from Child SKUs and set that number to Parent SKU

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to make a formula that will search amongst column D for parent (EX: 26013004) sku's child skus (EX: 26013004:26013004F, 26013004:26013004H, 26013004:R) then check for the lowest part quantity in stock.
So let's say **26013004:26013004F** has a quantity of 8, **26013004:26013004H** = 6, **26013004:26013004R** = 5. Since the lowest value is 5, parent sku **26013004** quantity will be changed to 5.
How would I start for this formula?

```
| SKU                | Quantity |
|--------------------|----------|
| 26013004           | 5        |
| 26013004:26013004F | 8        |
| 26013004:26013004H | 6        |
| 26013004:26013004R | 5        |
| 26015002           | 5        |
| 31003002:31003002B | 2        |
| 31003002:31003002T | 3        |
| 31004001           | 0        |
| 31004002           | 4        |
| 31004002:31004002A | 5        |
| 31004002:31004002B | 5        |
| 31005001           | 4        |
| 31005001:31005001A | 8        |
| 31005001:31005001B | 2        |
```

EDIT: So far I thought about using =IFERROR(LEFT(A3, SEARCH(":", A3) -1), "") to generate a C column with parent skus for child products while parent products will be blank. Next step I was thinking of using vlookup to look through column C's with the parent skus and find the smallest quantity using MIN. I'm stuck with how to put this all into a formula.

EDIT 2: I just realized some of the data will have the child sku's written without the PARENTSKU:CHILDSKU(A) so looking up for both options would be nice. Otherwise use this table as an example:

```
| SKU       | Quantity |
|-----------|----------|
| 26013004  | 5        |
| 26013004F | 8        |
| 26013004H | 6        |
| 26013004R | 5        |
| 26015002  | 5        |
| 31003002B | 2        |
| 31003002T | 3        |
| 31004001  | 0        |
| 31004002  | 4        |
| 31004002A | 5        |
| 31004002B | 5        |
| 31005001  | 4        |
| 31005001A | 8        |
| 31005001B | 2        |
```

Comment: If you post your data with [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) it is much easier to help you.

Comment: Just updated my post with the table

Comment: Will a main SKU always have a child?  I see examples where that is not the case but in that case, I assume the quantity against the SKU then remains, correct?

Comment: There will be main skus without childs. 31004001 is an example of one without any children skus and it will keep its quantity

Comment: Yeah, the Excel 2007 issue is a good one.  You should really look at upgrading.  Makes it pretty hard.  I got close but `MINIFS` isn't available in your version.  Would you consider a custom function through VBA?

Comment: Definitely would not mind VBA at all!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365, you can use Map to check each SKU and find the min matching quantity:

```
=IFERROR(MAP(A3:A16,LAMBDA(r,MIN(FILTER(B3:B16,LEFT(A3:A16,9)=r&":")))),B3:B16)
```

[image]

---

In Excel 2007, maybe you could add helper columns as shown in the centre of the image below, sort on SKU and quantity, then the min quantity would just be in the next row.

The formula in D2 is:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)=8,""&A2,LEFT(A2,8)&"C")
```

and the formula in H2 is:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(D2)=8,LEFT(D3,8)=D2),E3,B2)
```

[image]

If you decided to take the second scenario (starting at row 2) and write a formula for it in Excel 365, it would be:

```
=IFERROR(MAP(A2:A15,LAMBDA(r,MIN(FILTER(B2:B15,(LEFT(A2:A15,8)=r&"")*(LEN(A2:A15)=9))))),B2:B15)
```

Comment: This works great! But unfortunately I mainly work on 2007 excel. I'll be using this formula repeatedly so the less steps I need to get it to work the better.

Comment: If I had to do it in Excel 2007 I would be thinking about sorting it. Will add a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Will add to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions proposed:

- 1st uses two helper columns
- 2nd Uses two helper columns and a `PivotTable`

Both solutions have the data located at `[B6:C20]`

**Parent** (this column is common to both solutions)
Enter this formula at `[D7]`, then copy it to `[D8:D20]`

```
= IFERROR( LEFT( $B7, -1 +SEARCH( ":", $B7 ) ), TEXT(,) )
```

[image]

**Minimum** quantity
Enter this formula at `[F7]`, then copy it to `[F8:F20]`

```
= IF( LEN($D7), $C7,
 IF( COUNTIF( $D$7:$D$20, $B7 ) = 0, $C7,
 MIN( IFERROR( $C$7:$C$20 / (( $D$7:$D$20 = $B7 )*1), TEXT(,) ) ) ) )
```

That produces the following results:
[image]

---

The formulas above should work in Excel 2007, just in case here is the second solution ...

**PivotTable** Insert a pivotbale in `[J5]` using the range `[B6:D20]` as `SourceData`

**Minimum** quantity
Enter this formula at `[H7]`, then copy it to `[H8:H20]`

```
= IF( LEN($D7), $C7,
 IFERROR( VLOOKUP( $B7, $J$6:$K$13, 2, 0 ), $C7 ) )
```

That produces the following results:
[image]

Please try and let me know of any isuess\questions you may have.

Comment: Hi! I tried your first solution for 2007. The only issue that rises is that it takes the parent sku and sets it as the lowest. For an example:
| SKU       | Quantity |
|----------|----------|
| 26013004  | 0        |
| 26013004F | 8        |
| 26013004H | 6        |
| 26013004R | 5        |

It ends up setting 26013004 the parent sku as 0 instead of 5